# I can't Install Ubuntu or any Linux distros on my PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox

I was using Ubuntu for a long time. Last time I was using Ubuntu and windows dually. But before my project submission final day, there was a problem I faced while using Ubuntu. I reboot my pc for some reasons and then there was some grub related problem encountered. I couldn’t sure whether It was grub rescue problem or not. And as I was in a hurry the day before my project submission date so I installed windows quickly without solving that issue.

It was two months earlier incident. Now I am again trying to install different Linux distros on my pc but every time there is a unique problem I am facing right now. I can’t install any Linux distro on my pc. It stuck at some certain point. See this screenshot:

[image]

Actually, It takes a lot of time to install in a certain phase, more than 2 hours and it's unusual. I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Deepin, Elementary OS but none of these can’t install and stuck at the same point!

Even later I am trying to set up Linux by using the virtual machine but there I also face a problem that I haven’t encountered before. It shows the following message:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Looks like two separate issues. I think you should ask two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU supports only 32-bit(x86/i686). You should install only 32-bit(x86/i686) distributions.